# How to call a DBlink over a XA datasource

Tags: java, jdbc, datasource

I have a query which pulls a few records from another database via a DBlink.
This query works fine in Toad , or a plane JDBC connection or on a Non XA datasource connection. But when i try to use the same query on a XA datasource connection i starts giving an error as below.

java.sql.sqlexception: ora-24777: use of non-migratable database link not allowed

It seems because of XA datasource i am facing this issue. Is there a way to use a datalink on a XA datasource ? Please suggest any approach for that.

Answer (score 0):

i had to create a Non XA datasource to solve this purpose. XA datasources does not allow such queries. After using a Non XA based datasource  this was solved.